# Hide / Reveal available actions

Tags: jquery

I have a list:

```
<ul class="action">
<li>Available actions</li>
<li><a href="one.htm">One</a></li>
<li><a href="two.htm">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I would like to hide the available actions until the user hovers over them:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('ul.action a').hide();
    $('ul.action').hover(function() {
        $(this).filter('a').show('slow');
    },function() {
        $(this).filter('a').hide('slow');
    });
});
```

I think I don't understand what $(this) is yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [jQuery's `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [the `.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

In a jQuery event handler, `this` refers to the element matching the selector that received the event.

So here, `this` refers to the `<ul>` element. As such, you need to `.find()` the nested `<a>` elements.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('ul.action a').hide();
    $('ul.action').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('a').show('slow');
    },function() {
        $(this).find('a').hide('slow');
    });
});
```

When you use `.filter()`, you're checking the matched set (in this case the `<ul>`) to see if it finds any matches against the filter you give it (in this case `"a"`).

Because an `<a>` is never a `<ul>`, there would be no matches with `.filter()`.

---

As a side note, you can simplify your code like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tNTAa/

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('ul.action a').hide();
    $('ul.action').hover(function( e ) {
        $(this).find('a').toggle('slow', e.type === 'mouseover');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).find('a').show('slow');
```

instead of

```
$(this).filter('a').show('slow');
```

(and same for `hide`)

You want to find all child `a` elements of the current `ul`.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/
http://api.jquery.com/find/